# how to add custom columns to dataTables with server-side processing?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

i have made this example work on my page http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html, (using php5, jquery+ui and dataTables.net)

i would like to be able to add a Modify and Delete link on each row, how can i do that without sending two extra columns with the links from the server?

also how can i substitute the ids the rows have in the database and that are sent by the server with nice number starting from 1 till iTotalDisplayRecords...

thank you

Comment: What wrong with sending the two columns?

Comment: it looks like a bad solution to me, sending extra data to every ajax request, sending html code for links, what if path changes one day... it would be simplier if javascript could add it on the fly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found how

```
var controller_name = '<?php echo Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();?>';


"fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
                    /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */

                        for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
                        {
                            var link = $('&nbsp;<a href="/'+controller_name+'/modifica/id/'+ oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ]._aData[0]+'">Modifica</a> <a href="/'+controller_name+'/cancella/id/'+ oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ]._aData[0]+'">Cancella</a>');
                            $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
                            $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).append(link);
                        }
                },
```

Comment: using fnRowCallback is much faster and responsive than fnDrawCallback!!! (when having more than 500rows or stuff) and it doesn't give errors about script not responding